# sql server outer join?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I need to create a report based on this table structure:

[image: Table structure image]

To meet the requirement I created a SQL Server view using the below query:

```
SELECT doc.object_name as doc_name, 
       pack.object_name as pack_name, 
       pack.r_creation_date as pack_date 
FROM vale_eng_document_sp  doc
left outer join dm_relation_s rel on doc.r_object_id = rel.parent_id 
left outer join vale_eng_package_sp pack on rel.child_id = pack.r_object_id
WHERE
    doc.r_object_type='vale_eng_document' 
and doc.i_is_deleted = 0 
and (pack.i_is_deleted IS NULL or pack.i_is_deleted = 0) 
and (rel.relation_name IS NULL or rel.relation_name='AO Project Package')
```

For some values it shows 2 times the same document value as below:

```
DOCUMENT1      PACKAGE1    01/01/2016 00:00:00
DOCUMENT1      PACKAGE2    01/01/2017 00:00:00
DOCUMENT2      NULL        NULL
```

It happens because the same document is related to two or more packages.
If this situation occurs, the end user wants to only show the latest package based on `r_creation_date` attribute.

So they want to show this result:

```
DOCUMENT1     PACKAGE2    01/01/2017 00:00:00
DOCUMENT2      NULL        NULL
```

What changes do I need to make in my view to meet this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` to partition and find the most recent record, then filter from the derived table to only include the most recent record.

```
SELECT doc_name, pack_name, pack_date
FROM (
    SELECT doc.object_name as doc_name, pack.object_name as pack_name, pack.r_creation_date as pack_date,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY doc.r_object_id ORDER BY pack.r_creation_date DESC) AS RowNum
    FROM vale_eng_document_sp  doc
        left outer join dm_relation_s rel on doc.r_object_id = rel.parent_id 
        left outer join vale_eng_package_sp pack on rel.child_id = pack.r_object_id
    WHERE doc.r_object_type='vale_eng_document' 
        and doc.i_is_deleted = 0 
        and (pack.i_is_deleted IS NULL or pack.i_is_deleted = 0) 
        and (rel.relation_name IS NULL or rel.relation_name='AO Project Package')
    ) T
WHERE T.RowNum = 1 -- Only most recent record as requested
```

Comment: I think the partition is `BY doc.r_object_id` the left side of the `JOIN` because a doc can have multiple packages

Comment: Agreed, corrected answer. Thanks!